# Why can I not connect my laptop to a projector or TV?

Tags: projector

When I try to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to connect to projector or TV, Ubuntu will force logout.

I found that my settings can detect the TV.

[image: Screenshot of Displays manager, showing that Sony 65" is detected]

And I also found that nvidia-settings is weird.

It failed to detect my own screen.

[image: Screenshot of NVIDIA X Server Settngs, showing only X Screen 0]

I use nvidia-prime as my graphics driver.

I have also tested that other computers (including Windows 8 on my laptop) can connect to that TV. Only Ubuntu fails.